# Selenium Grid error on GitLab CI: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-grid, gitlab-ci, angularjs-e2e

Since documentation on GitLab CI configuration and Selenium is generally poor, I'm asking for help.

Configuration as by interest point:

`gitlab.ci.yml`:

```
image: node:7

variables:
  HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: "selenium__hub"
  HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: "4444"

services:
  - selenium/hub:latest
  - selenium/node-phantomjs:latest

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y default-jdk default-jre
    - npm install -s -g @angular/cli@1.0.6
    - npm install -s
    - node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/protractor protractor.ci.conf.js
```

`protractor.ci.conf.js`:

```
/*global jasmine */
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.binary.path': './node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs'
  },
  directConnect: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  },
  seleniumAddress: 'http://selenium__hub:4444/wd/hub'
};
```

With the above configuration, GitLab fails with:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/protractor protractor.ci.conf.js
(node:3702) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[09:53:27] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:53:27] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://selenium__hub:4444/wd/hub
[09:53:28] E/launcher - Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities [{phantomjs.binary.path=./node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs, count=1, browserName=phantomjs}]
[09:53:28] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities [{phantomjs.binary.path=./node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs, count=1, browserName=phantomjs}]
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
    at createDriver (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:167:33)
    at Builder.build (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:632:14)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.ts:60:29)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /builds/netaachen/operator-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
[09:53:28] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Cool, what is your question? :P

Comment: Sorry for not posing the question as obviously and leaving it to the title. I've included the failure stack now.

Comment: should base_url port be the same as the hub port? also, this might be useful to you https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1226

Comment: @nivesnine, it changed the result to `protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/ : retries looking for angular exceeded`. The problem does not relate to the page not having angular since e2e tests pass locally with the local protactor configuration (`baseUrl` set to http://localhost:4200/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use `Xvfb` on GitLab CI. That spins up the display so `--headless` Chrome can run the specs.

I wrapped more info and chunks of code into the blog post of [How to run AngularJS end-to-end tests on GitLab CI](https://tekkie.flashbit.net/devops/angular-e2e-tests-on-gitlab-ci).

Answer (score 1):

I have neved used Gitlab CI but have Selenium experience. So let me first describe some important considerations:

1. An error you receive means that there's no requested browser in the hub. This is probably because PhantomJS did not manage to register.
2. You don't need to install neither Java nor Selenium server to work with `PhantomJS`. It is a standalone binary implementing itself Selenium protocol. So in order to work with PhantomJS - just start container with PhantomJS. For example I would use this one: `selenoid/phantomjs:2.1.1` (build file is [here](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-images/blob/master/selenium/phantomjs/Dockerfile)) - it just runs `phantomjs --webdriver=4444`. PhantomJS by default listens on port `8910` but because of command above we can still use `4444`.
3. I think you also don't need to use `webdriver-manager` which is a Javascript tool to download Selenium server or webdriver binaries. This is not needed to work with PhantomJS.
4. Not sure why environment variables like `HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR` were added. So I would remove them all.

Having said that let's try to modify your files.

`gitlab-ci.yml` becomes:

```
image: node:7

services:
  - selenoid/phantomjs:2.1.1

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - npm install -s -g @angular/cli@1.0.6
    - npm install -s
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/protractor protractor.ci.conf.js
```

`protractor.ci.conf.js` becomes (only changed container name in `seleniumAddress`):

```
/*global jasmine */
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.binary.path': './node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs'
  },
  directConnect: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  },
  seleniumAddress: 'http://selenoid__phantomjs:4444/wd/hub'
};
```

Not sure what is `baseUrl` - seems to be some Protractor stuff, so I think don't need to change. Please ask more questions if any.

Comment: The above configuration is flawed due to following reasons:
a) `browsers.json` is missing for selenoid as documented at https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid
b) `aerokube/selenoid:2.1.1` does not exist, the highest tag currently is `1.3.2`. When fixed to `1.3.2`, selenoid will fail to launch with `2017-06-20T09:21:56.661951157Z 2017/06/20 09:21:56 /usr/bin/selenoid: browsers config: read error: open /etc/selenoid/browsers.json: no such file or directory`.

Comment: My error - needs to be `selenoid/phantomjs:2.1.1`, updated. You don't need Selenoid itself - just start container with Phantomjs.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've tried that, runs the specs but fails with `Failed: waiting for page to load for 10000ms`, so clearly failing to load the page from `localhost:4200` :(

Comment: Since Protractor 5 doesn't support PhantomJS any more, I also tried downgrading Protractor to `4.0.14`, but unfortunately without luck, it still times out. Looks like `baseUrl` is really the key problem here.

Comment: I think this is because localhost in container and localhost:4200 are two different things. You application under test starts somewhere outside Docker container and PhantomJS goes to localhost inside container - this is why it fails. So I think the solution is to reference baseUrl like `http://build__container:4200`, where `build__container` - is either some predefined alias for container where tests are run or host machine IP address if tests are run there.

Comment: GitLab has a convention that in the circumstances converts `service` to `selenoid__phantomjs` as you quite rightly denoted in your example, but it is not worknig. `http://selenoid__phantomjs:4200` times out as well as `http://selenoid__phantomjs:4444`.

Comment: Your tests start another server listening on port 4200 somewhere outside this container - this is why it does not work. You need to find how to access the tests container - not the PhantomJS one.